# timeIntervalSinceNow usage to get the time elapsed value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

My code looks something like this:

```
 NSDate *currDate;
 if(someCondition) {
   currDate = [NSDate date];
 }

  //do some work 

 //calculate num of milli seconds passed since currDate was updated 
 if([currDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > MAX_MILLI_SECS) {

   //do something
 }
```

So I have two questions here

1. Since currDate happens before we calculate timeIntervalSinceNow, is the value returned going to be negative?
2. Since there is a code path in which `currDate` is never initialized, what happens if I call `timeIntervalSinceNow` without having gone through the `if(someCondition)` block?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs for `-timeIntervalSinceNow`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1407937-timeintervalsincenow):

> If the date object is earlier than the current date and time, this property’s value is negative.

If the code is built with ARC enabled, then `currDate` is guaranteed to be initialized to `nil`. If the branch which sets it to something else is not taken, then it remains `nil` when `[currDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` is called. Messages to `nil` return the appropriate zero value for the type of the message. So, `[currDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` evaluates to 0.

If the code is not built with ARC enabled, then `currDate` will be uninitialized junk and the results are undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For me it's a bit confusing though, I assumed that a `nil` date would be interpret as 1 jan 1970.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a nil value doing timeIntervalSinceNow returns a NaN